# Decode a proprietary audio package format into mp3 file using bash

Tags: xml, bash, zip

I have a proprietary packaged file that is provided in the form of a .zip. The contents of these files always follows the same structure.

[image: Example]

In the root folder is an XML file (playlist) that lists the folders containing audio files.

Example:

```
<playlist>
    <playlistversion>1.0</playlistversion>
    <item>daudio\localaudio\Q2013\0989\0001\</item>
    <item>daudio\localaudio\Q2013\0989\0002\</item>
    <item>daudio\localaudio\Q2013\0989\0003\</item>
    <item>daudio\localaudio\Q2013\0989\0004\</item>
    <item>daudio\localaudio\Q2013\0989\0005\</item>
</playlist>
```

Each of these folders contains an audio file that is split into chunks with consecutively named extensions.

I need to write a script that does the following:

1. Unzips the packaged folder
2. Goes into each folder referenced in the playlist XML and joins each file it contains in the correct order.
3. Joins each of these joined files from each folder into one final master file.
4. Renames this master file the same as the original zip, but with an .mp3 filename

Here is an example file: http://cl.ly/aAwB

Comment: Is there a reason you have to do this in bash?  Bash is great for many things, but something like this might be better suited to a higher level scripting language (eg python, perl, ruby).

Comment: I'm more curious as to what leads you to believe that the results of this would be a valid mp3 file.

Comment: I know for a fact the files are in MP3 format. They just don't use the extension in this situation.

Comment: The script could be something else other than bash, my only requirement is that I could package it as a mac app I could then drag and drop a folder onto like you can with a bash file.

Comment: Plus-one for Python in that case.  Bash isn't really a good fit for this problem.

Comment: This question is a bit broad, but each folder of `*.a*` files contains a separate MP3, concatenating them all together won't produce a proper MP3 file, though it may still play in some players.

Comment: May I ask what have you tried?

Comment: Concating each folder of mp3 files and then concating the resulting files into a final single file does produce a playable file. I've done it manually with a concat gui tool. The problem I need to solve now is producing a script that can do this operation in a single process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a little script as

```
#!/bin/bash
[ ! -e $1 ]  && exit 9                  # Exit if file doesn't exists 
unzip -p $1 $(basename $1 .zip)/*/*/*/*/*.a* >$(basename $1 .zip).mp3
```

Notes:

- The first test `[ ! -e $1 ]` ensure the existence of the zip file
- The option `unzip -p`

> **-p**
>   extract files to pipe (stdout).  Nothing but the file data is sent to stdout, and the files are always extracted in binary  format,  just
>             as they are stored (no conversions).
>
> The first `basename` in the path is to avoid the `__MACOSX/` path to be extracted
>
> Finally `>` redirect to a new file that has the same name but `mp3` extension.
>
> ---

Ps> If you like to see it in only one line you can use

```
[ -e $1 ] && unzip -p $1 $(basename $1 .zip)/*/*/*/*/*.a* >$(basename $1 .zip).mp3
```

Both version will exit with code 0 if succeed, with code 9 if file is not found or with the exit code of unzip. 
I suggest you to add some additional controls to check if the output file just exists, if the input file is a zip file, if the extension is `.zip` ...

Comment: How do I go about running this and specifying the file? Sorry my bash skills are non existent.

Comment: If you call your script `go.sh`, after you make it executable (you change file mode bits)  _once and for all_ with `chmod u+x go.sh`, then you can run it with e.g. `./go.sh T20130553_27-05-2015.zip`.  Ps>Do not be sorry be curious!

Answer (score 0):

Use dd to merge the files with a bash script.

http://www.linuxquestions.org/linux/answers/applications_gui_multimedia/splitting_and_merging_files_using_dd

a for loop with find can locate all the files. And since they are named sequentially, you would just use dd and stat to link all the files together.

No need to overcomplicate the matter with python.